# TServerSocket и TClientSocket

Tags: delphi, клиент-сервер, ip

Есть ли возможность сканировать локальную сеть на активные ServerSocket и если есть получать ip адрес этого пк?

Comment: Какая цель данной манипуляции?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вывести список компьютеров с запущенной программой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решения не имеет. TServerSocket создает обычный слушающий порт. Снаружи нельзя узнать кто этот порт открыл.

Да. Вы можете в цикле перебрать все адреса в сети и для каждого адреса попытаться подключиться на известный Вам порт. Но это Вам ничего не даст

- Если Вам не удалось подключиться, то это может означать:

  - Порт никто не слушает (в том числе и Ваша программа)
  - Программа запущена, но подключения на этот порт блокируются брендмауэром
- Если Вам удалось подключиться, то не факт, что это именно Ваша программа

Единственный вариант решения, это если сервер выдает какой-то узнаваемый пакет при подключении или на какой-то запрос клиента